# Javascript Objects: Using Arguments as object property

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, arguments, coercion

I was reimplementing a memoize function using the Arguments object. I am wondering why this would work. For example, passing in 2 arguments:

```
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments); // input: 1,2
```

Then I would store the **args** array into an object. For Example,

```
var obj = {};
    obj[args] = 2;
```

If you were to call Object, you would see this as:

```
{ 1,2: 2 }/*shows as this*/  { [1,2]: 2 }/*but not as this*/
```

Not that I wanted the second object, just curious what is happening under the hood. Is this what you call Javascript coercion?

Comment: All property names are strings, so `args` is getting converted to a string, yes.

Comment: Using an array as an object property name won't really work very well. The array will be converted to a string first, and that result will be the actual name of the property.

Comment: Converting an array to a string works by doing `array.join(",")`

Comment: Ah, I see! Thanks you very much for the information. I wasn't sure what was happening, learning something new everyday!

Answer (score 1):

Object property names are always strings. So when you do:

```
obj[args] = 2;
```

it treats this as

```
obj[args.toString()] = 2;
```

And the `toString()` method of arrays is equivalent to `.join(",")`, so the above is equivalent to:

```
obj[args.join(",")] = 2;
```

which matches the result you saw.

Comment: Thank you so much, it makes a lot of sense! I was scratching my head for awhile lol.